# For loop over ResultSet#getFetchSize() in JSP doesn't produce any HTML

Tags: html, jsp, jdbc, scriptlet

I have the following code:

```
 <%
            for (int i = 0; i < rs.getFetchSize(); i++) {
                System.out.print("test");
                //blah
%>
        <div id="Test<%= out.print(i) %>">
            <div class="<%= oddOrEven(i)%>Header">
                <div class="<%= oddOrEven(i)%>A">Test<% out.print(i);%></div>
                <div class="<%= oddOrEven(i)%>B"> 
                //Stuff here
```

Odd or Even simply responds with the word odd or even based on the number i passed to it, that should make my css style alternate between grey colors.

When I compile the page it works, but this part is totally omitted and doesn't appear in the source.  Can someone help me get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ResultSet#getFetchSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getFetchSize%28%29) doesn't return the amount of returned records as you seemed to expect. It just returns the configured fetch size. It may for instance just return `0` depending on the JDBC driver configuration and semantics.

Just use [`ResultSet#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) [the usual way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) to move the cursor to the next row.

```
for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
```

---

That said, writing Java code in a JSP file is [officially discouraged since a decade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202). I'd suggest to work on that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<%
for(int i = 0; i < rs.getFetchSize(); i++)
{
%>
<div id="Test<%= i%>">
  <div class="<%= oddOrEven(i)%>Header">
     <div class="oddOrEven(i)A">Test<%= i%></div>

<%
}
%>
```

You are missing a last curly brace which will complete the for loop

Also you do not need to provide ... out.println() ... <%= %> will do that for you